# Iterating through a python array does not work

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

The following code spits out following:

```
...
6
)
,
 
(
'
1
9
2
.
1
6
8
.
0
.
5
9
'
,
 
6
0
7
1
,
 
'
1
9
2
.
1
6
8
.
0
.
1
9
9
'
,
 
0
,
 
6
)
]
```

The code:

```
f=open("example.txt", "r")
list=f.read()

for i in list:
    print(i)
```

example.txt: https://pastebin.com/uN5wVZKL

The example.txt looks like following: `[(IP,number,IP,number,number),(IP,number,IP,number,number),(IP,number,IP,number,number),...]`

I thought I could iterate through that array to get the first IP in every tuple in the array but it just iterates character through character instead of element through element.

What am I doing wrong?

*This question has been answered. Here's the end-product: https://pastebin.com/TaVKDVfU*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what are you trying to print out? Each tuple or each IP?  Just an FYI it's not an array in Python it is a list.

I have just done this.

```py
data = [('192.168.0.59', 2881, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6), ('192.168.0.199', 0, '192.168.0.59', 0, 1), ('192.168.0.59', 2882, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)]

for item in data:
   print(data)
```

And got the following:

```sh
('192.168.0.59', 2979, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)
('192.168.0.59', 2980, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)
('192.168.0.59', 2981, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)
('192.168.0.59', 2982, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)
('192.168.0.59', 2983, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)
```

But I have done the same as you and got the same:

```py
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

But if you were to do something like `print(type(data))` it would tell you it's a string. So that's why you're getting what you're getting what you're getting. Because you're iterating over each item in that string.

```py
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    new_list = data.strip("][").split(", ")

print(type(data)) # str
print(type(new_list)) # list
```

Therefore you could `split()` the string which will get you back to your list. Like the above...having said that I have tested the split option and I don't think it would give you the desired result. It works better when using `ast` like so:

```py
import ast

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    new_list = ast.literal_eval(data)

for item in new_list:
    print(item)
```

This prints out something like:

```
('192.168.0.59', 6069, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)
('192.168.0.59', 6070, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)
('192.168.0.59', 6071, '192.168.0.199', 0, 6)
```

##### Update

Getting the first IP

```py
import ast

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    new_list = ast.literal_eval(data)

for item in new_list:
    print(item[0])
```

Comment: I want to get each tuple and then use each tuple to get the first IPs in the tuples which are  the attacker IPs. The second IPs is the receiver and so not wanted.

Comment: Your last script (import ast) ... did what I want, thanks! By the way, your text has a some typos.

Comment: ha thanks for letting me know i'm mega tired. But glad it did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

The [print](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp) function in python has an 'end' parameter that defaults to newline `\n`.

Since each character is read in individually, `i` is a single character followed by `\n`

Try `print(i, end = '')`

Answer (score 0):

f.read() return the content of your text file in a string, you cannot convert it to a list of tuples.
Well, you could but using a lot of split() (I recomend to split on ")," or "(" to separate each tuple, then on "," to get each element of the tuple). Something like:

```py
with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
    your_list: list[tuples]

    # read the file as a string
    f_in_str: str = f.read()

    # removing useless characters
    f_in_str = f_in_str.replace("[", "")
    f_in_str = f_in_str.replace("]", "")
    f_in_str = f_in_str.replace("(", "")
    f_in_str = f_in_str.replace(" ", "")
    f_in_str = f_in_str.replace("'", "")

    # split it into a list
    tuples_in_str: list[str] = f_in_str.split("),")

    # convert str to tuples
    for tuple_str in tuples_in_str:
        # split() returns a list that we convert into a tuple
        a_tuple: tuple = tuple(tuple_str.split(","))
        your_list.append(a_tuple)
```

Note that i have not tested that code.

I strongly advise you, if you can, to change the format of your source to something like a csv. It will make things a lot easier in the futur.

Comment: No, I can't change the code. It's a variable from a foreign script. Changing the code might break it (It's an AI).